# Sticky faded gallery by scroller

Tags: scroll, gallery, sticky

I am trying to create a page with sections.
each section has text and image.
In mobile everything is scrolling normally.

However in Desktop I need to have all images stick to top
and upon scrolling between section the images needs to fade

**Example**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vqHjdar3-F9l38Ea15g8VVk1kg-CfgVf/view
(The second part on the short video)

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.56;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #878787;
}

.step {
  min-height: 90vh;
}

.wrap-gallery {
  position: fixed;
  /*   width: 45vw; */
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  right: 0;
}

.wrap-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap-gallery">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/dog">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/cat">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/bunny">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/bird">
  </div>

  <h2 class="d-block d-md-none">How the magic happens?</h2>
  <div class="row step step1">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class="d-none d-md-block">How the magic happens?</h2>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Mus mauris vitae ultricies
        leo integer malesuada nunc.</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last d-block d-md-none"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/dog"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row step step2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Mus mauris vitae ultricies
        leo integer malesuada nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last d-block d-md-none"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/cat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row step step3">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Mus mauris vitae ultricies
        leo integer malesuada nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last d-block d-md-none"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/bunny"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row step step4">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Mus mauris vitae ultricies
        leo integer malesuada nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last d-block d-md-none"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/380/bird"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```